# Django send-mail [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: django, email

I have problem in sending mail in `Django`

I set my gmail following this link:

- https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636278779262945155-948643181&rd=1#cantsignin

And i tried every solution online but still get `[Errno -2]`

I found someone said it is because the DNS problem ,can some one tell me what is wrong with my code and is there any solution ?

views.py

```
import django
from django import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def contact(request):
    send_mail('subject','message',settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,['zwt467875460@gmail.com'],fail_silently = False)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks')
def thanks(request): 
    return HttpResponse('thanks!')
```

settings.py

```
#email config
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gamil.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='zwt467875460@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='*********'        #my gmail password
EMAIL_USER_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FORM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/wenting/WTDjango/mysite/books/views.py", line 30, in contact
send_mail('subject','message',settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,['zwt467875460@gmail.com'],fail_silently = False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
return mail.send()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/mail/message.py", line 342, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py2.7.egg/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
[15/Apr/2017 18:45:56] "GET /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 500 102295
```

and in the Django error page:

```
Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py in create_connection, line 557
```

---

I guess my problem is that Gmail think i dont have a fixed or right DNS
so i cant create a socket

And then i tried sendmail :
after install sendmail ,sendmail-cf,and configure it ,

i tried :

```
 echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v zwt467875460@gmail.com
```

and the output is (i omit the sending details):

```
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <zwt467875460@gmail.com>... Connecting to smtp.gmail.com via relay...
050 <zwt467875460@gmail.com>... Deferred: Connection refused by smtp.gmail.com
250 2.0.0 v3GKMtLU003555 Message accepted for deliveryzwt467875460@gmail.com... Sent (v3GKMtLU003555 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 localhost.localdomain closing connection
```

The connection is refused by smtp.gmail.com

Comment: You have a typo in `'smtp.gamil.com'` as well as `DEFAULT_FORM_EMAIL` - Also you seem to be importing directly from django's core settings in your view and you likely want to reference your apps settings file.

Comment: thanks but i dnt think i have a typo in  smtp.gmail.com  as well as DEFAULT_FORM_EMAIL, maybe thats because i didn't catch your meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Check if IMAP/POP are enabled from your Gmail account settings.
Also check that access to 'less secure apps' is enabled .
If not, follow the link :https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Thanks but as i mentioned ,I already set the IMAP/POP in my gmail account .Do u set DNS specially for sendmail? Although i think i dnt need it in this situation...